# When using caching in Service workers, how to differentiate static from dynamic pages?

Tags: caching, service, service-worker

I've been reading about chaching strategies but, none of them seem to work for me.

I would like to get from cached files when they are statics but not if the link is navigation, otherwise it would get the cached content instead of the updated content on server / database.

I would also like to get it from cached when the browser is offline.